# Populating VBA array from a textbox

Tags: arrays, vba, textbox

I am trying to get the value of a textbox and save it to a string array by clicking a button.   I am getting a syntax error on the `name(0) = TextBox1.Text` line.   I will be making it a dynamic array once I figure out how to do it (that's why I have a `num` variable as well because the button can be clicked multiple times).

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim name(10) As String
   Dim num As Integer

   ' Debug.Print TextBox1.Text

   name(0) = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Name' is a built in name for excel.

Try:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim testArray(1 to 11) As String
   Dim num As Integer

   ' Debug.Print TextBox1.Text

   testArray(1) = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

EDIT: Changed the name of the array.

Comment: Hmm. could you printscreen the error and add it to your question please?

Comment: or wait, test this first: change the word 'name' it could be that it is a built in excel function or something and that could be causing the error

Comment: OMG! You're right. name is a built-in function. Time to properly name my variable now. Thanks a lot!!!!